# Android ViewPager refresh only one fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with a set of `fragments`, wich are all different, and takes time to load, and I need to refresh only one of those (say the 2nd one) when I move to it. I've also set `setOffscreenPageLimit` to the number of fragments I have

I tried using this method:

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if(position == 1) {
            pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

then to refresh:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof MyFragment ) {
        MyFragment f = (MyFragment ) object;
        if (f != null) {
            f.refreshStuff();
        }
    }

    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}
```

But with this approach it seems that when I select the second one and the `pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` gets called, it all gets kinda laggy.

Is there any better solution ?

thank you all

Comment: Having the same issue here. Were you able to find a good solution?

Comment: actualy i was able to find a better approach, see my solution

Answer (score 0):

So after a while I tried the following solution wich worked quiet well

first I defined an interface as follows:

```
public static interface FragmentState{
    void fragmentVisible();
}
```

this interface will be implemented it in many fragments, and will help me define what I want to do when a certain one becaumes visible

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentState {
    ...

    @override
    public void fragmentVisible() {
         //do specific stuff
         resetDataOrWhatever();
    }

}
```

then in my `ViewPager` i defined the `pageChangeListener` as follows, it is an example of the 2nd fragment that will do some stuff

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if(position == 1) {
            MyFragment fragment = mViewPager.getAdapter().getItem(1);
            // call the fragmentVisible method here
            fragment.fragmentVisible();
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

hopefully this will help some people, ALSO, if there is a better solution please provide us with it

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you really don't have to refresh the entire fragment, you could try overriding the onResume method of the fragment and make the appropriate changes. This is really not a good approach if you're trying to achieve complete layoout change. But if you're looking for small UI changes or database interation, then you could try out this solution.